# Setting up Anaconda 2 with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I want to run Jupyter Lab (Notebook) with ArcPy. I have ArcMap 10.7 with Python Version 2.7.15, Numpy=1.9.3, matplotlib=1.5.2.

I followed the instructions from the following link:

https://gisday.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/setting-up-anaconda-pysal-with-arcgis-python-environment/
and I have downloaded Anaconda 2 32-bit.

I can only run the Anaconda Powershell Prompt as an Administrator, but this option does not exist for the Anaconda prompt (I do not know whether this makes a difference...).

The problem I have occurs when running the command:

> conda create -n arc107 python=2.7.15 numpy=1.9.3 matplotlib=1.5.2
>   pyparsing xlrd xlwt pandas scipy ipython ipython-notebook
>   ipython-qtconsole

I get the following error: 
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: 
then it lists: matplotlib=1.5.2, ipython-notebook, ipython-qtconsole

I deinstalled Anaconda and reinstalled it again, but it does not work. I also did not get the thing running with Anaconda 3, 32-bit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We have some clues here that may help you

[Using Anaconda modules from the ESRI python environment](https://my.usgs.gov/confluence/display/EGIS/Using+Anaconda+modules+from+the+ESRI+python+environment)

(So sad I am retired and now "unknown user")